# How could i get names and values within json string i have

Tags: c#, json

How could I get names and values within `json` string I have:

```
{
  "AccYearsList": [
    {
      "start_date": 1453766400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 1485302400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1454198400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 1485734400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1382400
    },
    {
      "end_date": 32918400
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1453852800
    },
    {
      "end_date": 1485388800
    },
    {
      "start_date": 1453852800
    },
    {
      "end_date": 1485388800
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be doable with use of [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)
However it's possible the deserializer will not be able to deserialize your string as it is. In this case you can preliminary transform the string into a form 'understandable' to the deserializer.

Another possible way is to use [Regex Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx). Something like as follows:

```
            const string inputStr = "{" +
                                "\"AccYearsList\": [" +
                                "{\"start_date\": 1453766400}," +
                                "{\"end_date\": 1485302400}," +
                                "{\"start_date\": 1454198400}," +
                                "{\"end_date\": 1485734400}," +
                                "{\"start_date\": 1382400}," +
                                "{\"end_date\": 32918400}," +
                                "{\"start_date\": 1382400}," +
                                "{\"end_date\": 32918400}]}";

        const string pattern = @"start_date.:\s*(\d+)}.+?end_date.:\s*(\d+)}";

        var re = new Regex(pattern);
        var matches = re.Matches(inputStr);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var startDate = match.Groups[1];
            var endDate = match.Groups[2];

            Console.WriteLine("start_date: '{0}'", startDate);
            Console.WriteLine("end_date: '{0}'", endDate);
        }
```